# SQL Server Management Studio: F4 equivalent Toad shortcut

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

In Toad for Oracle you can put the cursor on the name of a object and press <kbd>F4</kbd> to open it's definition.

Is there anything similar in T-SQL / SQL Server Management Studio ides?

Comment: Any chance you could use Toad for SQL Server? I don't think the "normal" Mgmt Studio has anything comparable

Comment: Toad for SQL Server is better than "normal" Mgmt Studio?

Comment: I don't know - never seriously looked at it - but it might offer that F4 functionality you're looking for ....

Comment: @marc_s: and usually how do people behave in mgmt studio when they need to open something that can be a table or a view?

Comment: I normally keep the `Object Explorer` open on the left and that treeview of my database objects is quite good enough for me

Comment: @marc_s: thanks.. however I was complaining that toad was unstable but mgmt studio seems a bit a "basic" tool.. maybe I don't know it enough well

Comment: @EricZ: seems nice! Answer so I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have developed [SSMSBoost](http://www.ssmsboost.com) add-in for SQL Server Management Studio and it does exactly what you want. The shortcut is F2

Comment: Seems nice. Why don't you give free licenses of your program to the user of StackExchange? It would help a lot at making it known

Comment: Please write me a short e-mail to support@ address (it's me) and we can discuss your idea.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the definition of an object, the procedure sp_helptext will give that to you. As for assigning it to a keyboard shortcut in SSMS, you can do so by going to Tools → Options → Keyboard → Query Shortcuts and assigning sp_helptext to one of the available slots. Once that's done, highlight the name of an object in your query editor window, hit the assigned shortcut and it should display the definition. As someone mentioned above, sp_help will get you different information (i.e. columns, indexes, constraints, etc) if the object is a table or a view. Luckily, the same process applies to sp_help!

Comment: You can even use your own Stored Procedures and assign keyboard shortcuts to it. The only constraint is that they have to be in master DB and its name start with *sp_*